# $.ajax POST issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use `ajax` **POST** method to validate course number on my page. The `helper.html` sends back correct value of i (`true` or `false`); that sets `ValidCourse` to true when it is a valid course.  But when I check the value of `ValidCourse` after the ajax call; it always remains '`false`'. Why?

```
if (EnrollmentsCount == 0) { // validate course 
    var crsNum = "'" + $j("#course_number").val() + "'";
    var ValidCourse = false;
    // Ajax call to determine if course is valid course 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'helper.html?crsNum=' + crsNum,
        async: false,
        success: function(i) {
            if (i === 'true') {
                ValidCourse = true;
            }
        }
    });

    if (!ValidCourse) { //it is always false whether it is a valid or invalid course        
        var errorMsg = "Please enter valid course number";
        scroll('#course_number');
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact value that helper.html responds with?

Comment: Why are you using `async: false`?  This is almost always a *bad* idea.

Comment: What does `console.log(i)` show you inside the `success` callback?

Comment: I think it is because your check on validcourse is outside the callback function. It is checked before the ajax post call has returned its result.

Comment: @Jkike I thought so as well, but he is using  async: false

Comment: @GlenSolsberry helper.html returns 'true'. Firebug shows that it is setting the  ValidCourse = true;

Comment: @Jkike I tried it inside the function too, but no luck. async:false was to beat the synchronous of AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, your problem might be the `===` operator which you're using.

I think your html page's return value of `true` is being treated as boolean by javascript, then `i` has a boolean value, but you're checking against a string in `'true'`. So try your test as `if(i === true)`

Need the contents of html page for further debugging mate!

Comment: the return value from html page is a boolean. I am using `===` three equal signs to set ValidCourse variable, converting from string to boolean. html page is simply a query to check against the database if course exists or not. It is returning true or false.

Comment: Well then, could be the scope issue. Try putting your `if (!ValidCourse)` condition's code _inside_ the `if (i === 'true')` function.

Answer (score 1):

the scope of the variable end when the callback method has done its execution. you might want to consider other option to check the value or put the program logic in the success callback function. this way you will achieve what you want.

Comment: I tried the following code `if (EnrollmentsCount == 0) { 
   var crsNum = "'" + $j("#course_number").val()  + "'";
   var ValidCourse = false;    
   $.ajax ({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'editsechelper.html?crsNum=' + crsNum,
     async: false,
     success: function(i) {
       if ( i === 'false' ){       
        valid = false;
        var errorMsg="Please enter valid course number";
scroll('#course_number'); }
     }
   });
` It does not set the values for errormsg and valid (boolean variable) when an invalid course # is entered.

Comment: you need to handle the condition for true as well. As i can see from the code, u r only handling if the condition is false. You may want to handle the condition for true statement as well.if ( i === 'false' ){ valid = false; var errorMsg="Please enter valid course number"; scroll('#course_number'); }  else { valid=true" errorMsg = "";}

Comment: Sorry it still totally ignores the invalid courses (false value) and works with valid courses. I need to catch the invalid data.

Comment: awesome Kaur. Glad you found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

can i see source code in helper.html ?

maybe this problem you use

```
var crsNum = "'" + $j("#course_number").val()  + "'";
```

try to use

```
var crsNum = $("#course_number").val();
```

Comment: it works either way. The html page works fine; giving me true for valid and false for invalid course. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The return value from helper.html had line feed and space. The following took care of it. Thanks everyone!

```
if ( i.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()  === 'true' ) {  
    ValidCourse = true;
            }
        }
    });
```